# Why is this trying to insert multiples?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following method

```
public static Artist ProcessArtist(Artist artist, Entities db) {
    var artistLookup = db.Artist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ExternalId == artist.ExternalId);
    if (artistLookup == null) {
        artistLookup = new Artist {
            ExternalId = artist.ExternalId,
            Name = artist.Name
        };
        db.Artist.AddObject(artistLookup);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return artistLookup;
}
```

The way I'm using it is that I pass in an `Artist` object that just has `ExternalId` and `Name` set, but it's not connected to my entity context at all. It was grabbed from an external source.

When I call `db.SaveChanges()` it throws, saying I've broken my unique key constraint for `ExternalId`. I can't figure out how it would be trying to insert multiples.

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks!

EDIT: I've added my calling code below

```
var albums = from item in externalSource
             select new Album {
                 Country = country // Another entity, one that exists in the database
                 Name = item["Name"].Value,
                 Artist = new Artist {
                     ExternalId = Int32.Parse(item["ArtistId"].Value),
                     Name = item["ArtistName"].Value
                 }
             };
```

then I call `ProcessArtist` for each album

```
foreach (var album in albums) {
    album.Artist = ProcessArtist(album.Artist, db);
    db.Album.AddObject(album);
}
```

Comment: What stops it is the lookup check. It looks in the DB (first line of method) and if it didn't find it, it tries to insert it. I have also manually checked and the table is empty. `ExternalId` is coming from an RSS feed. `ExternalId` is unique.

Comment: Is ExaternalId an IDENTITY primary key in the table?

Comment: No it's just a `bigint` with a unique constraint

Comment: On a tangent here.. why are you passing your DbContext as a parameter, can you isolate the ProcessArtist transaction maybe add a using statement in your method and avoid passing the Entities context. Perhaps preceeding code is interfering with this one.

Comment: This is rather strange. I use EF almost the exact same way. You say the table is empty, maybe there's something wrong with the database schema versus what EF thinks it is. Try saving the context without any changes (before the null check) and see if it throws there too.

Comment: @BZink Your idea put me in the right direction, I think! My calling code assigns `artist` with `new Artist { ExternalId = externalId, Name = name }`. I think what's happening is that is adding the new `Artist` object to the context? I tried adding `db.Detach(artist);` at the top of the method. That didn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
var artistLookup = db.Artist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ExternalId == artist.ExternalId);
//in this line  you get an artist from the database


//i dont know why would you want to insert the artist that you just get from the database
//you are reinserting an existing record. That's the reason you get the error
    db.Artist.AddObject(artistLookup);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Look at the null check. I'm checking to see if it is in the database. I insert if it isn't found.

Comment: instead of using db.artist.singleordefault use db.artist.any(a=> a.externalid==artist.externalid) this return you a bool telling you if exists or not

Comment: I don't see how that fix an insert issue. That statement is a select. Also, I need to return an `Artist` object with the specified `ExternalId` which exists in the database. That is what the function is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your for loop, I don't think the error is because of Artist entity, but it may be a different entity as in every step in for loop, you are saving context after adding the Artist but you have pending added albums and it may be having key violation for album that was still pending.

Ok I got it, When you are assigning artist, you still have other albums that exist without Ids and when you add or attach anything to object context, entire object graph gets attached. Now here the problem is, you are reusing objects created before.

In your code, where you are creating objects from rss, don't use entities, instead use some proxy class. For example RAlbum and RArtist and in your for loop change it.

var albums = from item in externalSource;
     select new RAlbum {
          Country = country // Another entity, one that exists in the database
                 Name = item["Name"].Value,
                      Artist = new RArtist {
                         ExternalId = Int32.Parse(item["ArtistId"].Value),
                         Name = item["ArtistName"].Value
                     }
                 };

```
public static Artist ProcessArtist(RArtist artist, Entities db) {
    var artistLookup = db.Artist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ExternalId == artist.ExternalId);
    if (artistLookup == null) {
        artistLookup = new Artist {
            ExternalId = artist.ExternalId,
            Name = artist.Name
        };
        db.Artist.AddObject(artistLookup);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return artistLookup;
}


foreach (var album in albums) {
    Album a = new Album();
    // copy properties of a from album
    a.Artist = ProcessArtist(album.Artist, db);
    db.Album.AddObject(a);
}
```

Comment: I know what the problem is now but I don't know what to do about it. I forgot that there is another entity I was assigning in my LINQ query expression. I've added a line with a comment up in my question. I think Entity Framework is connecting the new Album and Artist objects back to the context using the country assignment. I think if I just add my foreign key columns to my model I can just do it that way. Any thoughts?